# Apparent Bug in apache-camel Throttler component

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, throttling

I have observed that apache-camel doesn't throttle the requests as expected when the `rejectExecution`(see below) is `true`

```
<throttle timePeriodMillis="10000" rejectExecution="true">
    <constant>4</constant>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
</throttle>
```

Following is code snippet from `org.apache.camel.processor.Throttle` class

```
    protected long calculateDelay(Exchange exchange) {
    ......
    TimeSlot slot = nextSlot();
            if (!slot.isActive()) {
                long delay = slot.startTime - currentSystemTime();
                return delay;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
    }


/*
 * Determine what the next available time slot is for handling an Exchange
 */
protected synchronized TimeSlot nextSlot() {
    if (slot == null) {
        slot = new TimeSlot();
    }
    if (slot.isFull() || !slot.isPast()) {
        slot = slot.next();
    }
    slot.assign();
    return slot;
}
```

As per above snippet whenever a slot is full and a new request arrives, then a new slot beginning after the current slot is created and `slot.assign()` is invoked to reduce the capacity of this newly created slot to accommodate current request which according to me is faulty as there will be a delay in processing this new request and as per the Throttler code whenever there is a delay and `rejectExecution = true` a 
`org.apache.camel.processor.ThrottlerRejectedExecutionException` is thrown. It's obvious that even though the Throttler component is rejecting the new request after the threshold is reached still it is reducing the capacity of the next slot which will allow one less request to be processed in the next slot rather than the same number as of previous slot.

Comment: It makes sense to report bugs to [Apache Camel Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL)

Comment: Thanks @Alexander . I have raised an issue in [Apache Camel Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL)